# Why am I encountering "Preview Universal Scene Description Package 0 КВ" error?

Tags: roomle

After clicking an AR button in the configurator and scanning QR code with an iPhone I get an error "Preview Universal Scene Description Package 0 КВ". The error appears only sometimes but I don't see any connections with configurations. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7VGp.png)

I updated system to the newest version and use Safari.